# My ethernet internet doesn't work, the Network icon shows a question mark

Tags: networking, 22.04, internet, ethernet

My Ethernet internet had always worked without a problem on my Laptop (ThinkPad t450), until about a week ago, when suddenly the Ethernet stopped working (only the Ethernet, the Wifi works well on the laptop), I already ruled out that it was my cable ethernet or the router, since using them I can connect to the Internet on another PC without problem.  I am using Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Have you checked (in Wired Settings) what connection it is using? It may have inadvertently switched to a different configuration.